# How to fix this code not adding information?

Tags: python, set

I want to have a `def` in which it'll add the other "Persons" ID to its set.

```
class People:

    def __init__(self, name="anon"):
        if name == "anon":
            self.myname = makeRName()  ####Random Name
        else:
            self.myname = name
        self.friends = {} 
        self.mutualf = {}

    def addFriend(self, other):
        self.friends.add(other.ID)

    def showFriends(self):
        print(self.friends)

    def makeMutual(self, other):
        mutual = self.friends.intersection(other.friends)
        self.mutual.add(mutual)
        self.friends.remove(mutual)
```

I expect the ID to be added to the set, but get:

```
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'`
```

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is `dict` literal syntax, not of `set`. You need the `set` callable to create an empty set:

```
self.friends = set() 
self.mutualf = set()
```

Now you can use the `set` methods on them.